# jq math function adding large float number

Tags: jq, precision, python-3.8

I have a jq function that is adding a large float number to a simple math function.
Does anyone know what is causing this large float number? My colleague runs the same function on his laptop and doesn't get the large float. He only gets two decimal floats. Seems like a local things.

Running on Mac Mojave(yeah need to update)

Large Floats

```
cat VIAC.json | jq '.underlyingPrice - (.callExpDateMap[][][] | select(.putCall == "CALL").bid)'
41.540000000000006
41.790000000000006
```

Actual numbers

```
cat VIAC.json | jq '.underlyingPrice'
42.34

cat VIAC.json | jq '.callExpDateMap[][][] | select(.putCall == "CALL").bid'
0.8
0.55
```

Expected values

```
41.54
41.79
```

I know I can use awk and other functions to get what I need, but would like to understand why this is happening.

Thanks

===

Seems like it's related to python3

```
Python 3.8.6 (v3.8.6:db455296be, Sep 23 2020, 13:31:39)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> 42.34 - 0.8
41.540000000000006
>>>
```

Anyone know why python3 does this?

Found this for the problem
https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://floating-point-gui.de/ explains it pretty nicely.

Seems like I'll have to use awk to get the output i want.